# How do I make my app not switch themes while in game

Tags: android, kotlin, android-theme, material-components-android, android-dark-theme

I'm doing a simple Math game for Android and it turns on dark mode on/off depending on the system settings; I used `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar` as my theme's parent. However, I don't want the game to suddenly change themes in-game for it'll be jarring to the user and the redrawing of the screen will cause a jitter (and possibly, bugs).

I want to make the app not change themes until the game ends and I will just call `fun syncTheme()` or something to sync the theme with the system settings in another activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add
`android:configChanges="uiMode"` to the `<activity>` element for your game in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.  This will [prevent you from receiving configuration change events](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config) by declaring that you will handle UI mode changes (which includes [night mode and car/desk modes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager)) yourself manually.